# How can I insert and variable in between 2 strings in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code:

```
@pageb=2

<a data-remote="true" href="/?activities_page= @pageb &partial=true&render=activities"> >> </a>
```

URL I want:

```
http://localhost:9292/?activities_page=   2   &partial=true&render=activities
```

URL I get:

```
http://localhost:9292/?activities_page=   %20@pageb%20   &partial=true&render=activities
```

Comment: I tried to format your code but there's a lot of spaces in there that make no sense. Maybe you can clean that up?

Comment: To interpolate in Rails you use either `#{@pageb}` (for regular strings) or `<%= @pageb %>` (for ERB). Currently this question is not possible to answer with the limited information you've given, please edit it to add more info.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you should never build URLs by string concatenation. That is error-prone and you might end up with invalid URLs easily. Ruby on Rails has helper methods to build and escape URLs properly.

You didn't provide much context but in your case, something like this might work:

```
<%= link_to ' >> ', 
    root_path(activities_page: @pageb, partial: true, render: 'activities'),
    data: { remote: true } %>
```